# Total run time of multiple queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I have some benchmark queries in a .sql file. If i use source in mysql to execute them, mysql will show run time after each query. And there are pages and pages query outputs. Is there any way that I can obtain the total run time of all queries?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: subtract earliest timestamp from latest lol

Comment: are they being logged to a table or are we left to wonder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions.
I end up created another table just to record the start and end time of each query in the .sql file.

I edited the .sql file, add an insert statement after each original query just to record the time. At the end, I can query this "time" table for profiling the .sql file execution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use MySQL's built in profiling support by adding this line to your `my.cnf`:

```
SET profiling=1;
```

This allows you to easily see the time it took for each query:

```
mysql> SHOW PROFILES;
+----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration    | Query                                                             |
+----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 |  0.33174700 | SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE extra LIKE '%zkddj%'           | 
|        2 |  0.00036600 | SELECT COUNT(id) FROM myTable                                     | 
|        3 |  0.00087700 | CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo LIKE myTable                           | 
|        4 | 33.52952000 | INSERT INTO foo SELECT * FROM myTable                             | 
|        5 |  0.06431200 | DROP TEMPORARY TABLE foo                                          | 
+----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can them sum up the times to get the total time:

```
SELECT SUM(Duration) from information_schema.profiling;
```

You can find more details on MySQL's profiling [here](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/mysql-servers-built-in-profiling-support/).

Another approach you could take it to run execute the SQL queries from command line and use the Unix `time` command to time the execution. This may, however, not give you the most precise time though. Additionally, it won't give you a breakdown of how long each query took unless you use it in combination with MySQL profiling.

Comment: Thanks a lot, aam1r. Is there a way to show just query and duration. My queries are too long and it is difficult to view. Or is there any way that I can query this "profiles" table? If I am going to run the benchmark again, how to clean up the profiles table?

Comment: @AlfredZhong: I haven't tried this but I would suggest trying running queries off `information_schema.profiling` -- just like we are to get the total sum. So, `SELECT Query_ID, Duration FROM information_schema.profiling` to get just the query ID and duration. Maybe there's a better way to do it. I would love to know about it if there is.

Answer (score 1):

you could modify your .sql to create a begin and end row with a timestamp and then subtract without having to bring out an excel spreadsheet and add it up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Drew. What is the syntax of mysql to put a timestamp?